# Error, can anybody help me

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm getting this error while trying to run a page:

```
ERROR:

500 | Internal Server Error | PropelException
Unable to open PDO connection [wrapped: could not find driver]
```

What is the problem, what do I need to do to eliminate this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look in php.ini and enable the appropriate PDO driver for your RDBMS vendor. For MySQL you need to uncomment php_pdo_mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at PHPInfo(); to check if you have successfuly uncommented required driver.

Don't forget to restart apache after modifying php.ini ;-)